# bash split command not splitting file within python

Tags: python, bash, split

Found some rather strange behaviour here.  I would like to split a file via python subprocess. Here is the bash command:

`$ split -l 10000 /tmp/folder/file prefix`

This works in the terminal. However, in python:

```
subprocess.call(["split", "-l", "10000", "/tmp/folder/file", "prefix"])
# and
os.system("split -l 10000 /tmp/folder/file prefix")
```

Both do nothing (except return status code 0).
But only for splitting. They work as they are supposed to with everything else that I'm doing.

Any ideas what the issue may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python will not always set the working directory to the directory you launch it from. Is it possible that the split files are stored in a different working directory than you are expecting?

To check:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

If you need to:

```
os.chdir("/tmp/folder")
```